# How to combine data from these two tables in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables, one for resources and another for required assignment.

For instance:

| Resource | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 8 |

| Required | Count |
| --- | --- |
| X | 4 |
| Y | 3 |
| Z | 5 |

The resources table tells how many things I've got from each resource and the required table tells how many resources I need for this item.

In the above example:

- For X we need to assign 3 times A and 1 time B.
- For Y we need to assign 1 time B and 1 time C.
- For Z we need to assign 5 times C.

We will have spare C items…

Currently, I've tried to add calculated columns for both tables:

| Resource | Count | Accumulated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 8 | 13 |

| Required | Count | Accumulated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 4 | 4 |
| Y | 3 | 7 |
| Z | 5 | 12 |

My main issue is how to have a formula that will know to split one resource into multiple assignments or one assignment from multiple resources.

In the original attempts, we did cartesian multiplexing of both above tables but didn't succeed…

Can someone suggest a clue?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Resource assignment - like resource deployment - this is not a homework assignment. I have different types of resources that can suit into the same buckets and I need to assign a resource into a bucked. please review my profile to see that I've finished university quite long ago...

Comment: @yossico If that is the case, then you really need to reword your question and also show what you have done so far. I went ahead and re-edited your question and used markdown [table formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) to make this all clearer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Except from what I've added in the edit, I didn't have any good progress on that, I did many tryouts but all came quickly to a dead end. BTW, thanks for the table markdown haven't heard of it till now.

Comment: @yossico - As reviewers we are encouraged never to review the user but review the contribution.  Most users never bother filling out anything in their profile, like myself.